# bluebird pattern for mocking asynchronous promises with syncronous code

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm just getting started with bluebird (and node more generally).

I am wanting to create some mocks (for what will ultimately be either http or database calls).

All the talk of antipatterns has me anxious :-)

So is this a reasonable approach for converting this synchronous code into promises?

I have two simple functions here. The second calls the first (not in way the prod service would) but it serves as an illustration of nesting promises.

```
// mock function to return a promise of a collection        
var getTestPatients = function(params) {                    
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {            
    setTimeout(function() {resolve(test_patients);}, 200);  
  })                                                        
}; 

// mock function to return a promise of an object           
var getTestPatient = function(params) {                     
  return getTestPatients().then(function(patients) {
    // wouldnt get entire patient list in prod - but this works for a mock
    var patient = _.find(patients, {urn: params.urn});      
    if (patient) {                                          
      patient.reviews = testReviews(params.uid);            
    }                                                       
    else {                                                  
      throw new Error('patient not found');                 
    }                                                       
    return Promise.resolve(patient);                        
  });                                                       
};
```

A couple of things these are demonstrating:

- creating a fake delay
- creating a promise from synchronous code
- manipulating a promise result within a function that makes a promise
- throwing errors

So quite a few things I could have gotten wrong.

How did I do? Any anti-patterns in here? or other rookie errors?

Comment: Change `return Promise.resolve(patient);  ` to just `return patient;`.  No need to create a new resolved promise and just return it.  You can just return the value itself.

Comment: FYI, if you know this is working code and you want improvement suggestions, then you can take it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Using both `getTestPatient` and `getTestPatients` as function names makes it easy to get confused when reading the code.

Comment: sweet thanks @jfriend00 changing `return Promise.resolve(patient);` to just `return patient;` did indeed work! and feels better :-) - I can do that because I'm already in a `then()` right? (btw you should post as an answer shouldn't you?)

Comment: Yes, the return value from a `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of the promise.  Similarly a thrown exception value becomes the rejected value of the promise.  It is the `.then()` promise infrastructure that calls your `.then()` handler and thus receives the return value or catches the exception that makes this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No antipatterns and no mistakes to see here. However, two things you could improve:

- Whenever you find yourself using the `Promise` constructor, first try to find a simpler way. Is there already a function that does return a promise for the desired task? `setTimeout` is a genuine callback-based API, so nothing *wrong* here, but given that you're using Bluebird you could remove that boilderplate by just using the [`Promise.delay`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.delay.html) helper function:

  ```
  function getTestPatients = function(params) {                    
      return Promise.delay(test_patients, 200);      
  }
  ```
- The call to `Promise.resolve` in the `then` handler is unnecessary. Just as you can `throw` exceptions, you can `return` plain values and they will be automatically wrapped. So cleaner-looking is just

  ```
  return patient;
  ```